# How do you go to next line after creating a horizontal list?

Tags: html, css

As illustrated in the following screenshot, the `<p>` element is being displayed on the same level as the `<ul>` which precedes it. I wish the `<p>` element to be diplayed underneath the `<ul>`:

[image: Screenshot here]

Is there a way that I can control all the elements inside `divMain` at once? I want all the three `<ul>` elements and the `<p>` element to be displayed underneath each other to the left-most side.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container" id="divMain">
    <form method="post" action="add.php">
        <ul class = "verticalList">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class = "horizontalList">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <p>This sentence should appear on a separate line. </p>
        <ul class = "verticalList">
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </form> 
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.horizontalList{
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: can you post the css you are using?

Comment: a `<p>` tag there already would appear on a separate line.

Comment: Am I the only one or is the attached screenshot actually missing ?

Comment: Just say `<p>` is a block.. in your CSS

Comment: Replicated & looks fine at my side. There must be some CSS on your side which is making the `<p>` inline element (default should have been block element) with the preceding `<ul>`

Comment: you better post your css for a better answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container" id="divMain">
<form method="post" action="add.php">
    <ul class = "verticalList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class = "horizontalList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <p style="display:inline-block; overflow: hidden; clear: both;">This sentence should appear on a separate line. </p>
    <ul class = "verticalList">
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I dont know the css of the classes but I think the code above will work. Just for debugging you might want to use !important.

Answer (score 0):

you need a clear:both after the floating elements or display:inline-block for the horizontal elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the relative position with CSS.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

But if you want an responsive page, use Bootstrap or Foundation. I hope to have helped you with the relative position...

Answer (score 0):

```
form {
display: block
}
```

this will set the DOM elements inside form one below eachother